Ubuntu DNS server and TXT records
I have a Ubuntu v22 VM serving as DNS secondary for numerous domains.  When querying this server, all domains except 1 respond fine to all queries. The one exception domain responds fine to all record queries except any TXT records. If i lookup a TXT record from this server, for this domain, it times out.   Doing the same query to the primary DNS server responds fine.
Any suggestions as to what i should look for?

It might be that your firewall blocks TCP DNS port 53 and only allows UDP. Larger responses use TCP

I think, it's not as important which distro you're running, as what software you're running for DNS server. BIND? PowerDNS? Anything else?

I'm running standard bind on Ubuntu 22.04.04

Check the zone transfer logs on both the primary and secondary DNS servers for errors related to the problematic domain. Ensure the primary server is correctly configured to allow zone transfers (AXFR) to the secondary server. Manually trigger a zone transfer using rndc retransfer <zone_name> on the secondary or rndc reload <zone_name> on the primary and check for any errors. Verify the zone files on both servers for discrepancies and ensure there are no ACLs or network issues blocking the transfer of TXT records.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
